# what path planning method does GMAPPING-based navigation use?

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, path, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone.
I have been working with the gmapping-based map to practice a room environment navigation test. However, there were something that the performance is not satisfied. The problem is that my robot trembled while executing navigation task via rviz.
So, I am not sure that whether this is a problem of localization method specifying via 'Pose Estimation' button or the problem about path planning algorithm.
Thanks.

This is my previous post about this phenomenon.
http://answers.ros.org/question/3632/how-can-i-revise-the-velocity-that-ros-set-for?answer=5678#5678

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12810/what-path-planning-method-does-gmapping-based-navigation-use?/) by [letmoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1610/letmoon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-01-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

GMapping is actually only responsible for map generation, so if you already have generated a map, that should not have anything to do with your problem.

For localization i guess you use AMCL? You can check if you are correctly localized by visualizing your laser scans (if you use laser) and check if the alignment with the map is correct. The "Pose Estimation" is only an initial guess for AMCL localization, so this should not be a problem...

If it is, the problem is probably caused by the planner. You can visualize the plan of the global planner in RVIZ and check if it is correct. In your case of a "trembling" i would probably guess that your problem is caused by the local planner... you should first check if you local planner receives the laser scans, odometry information and pose. Using rxgraph, you can check if the topics are correctly connected. If everything is fine, you can use rxconsole and set the logger-levels of each node (one after another) to "Debug" to check for error messages...

Can you also provide some more information about you robot/sensors/map?

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [letmoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1610/letmoon/) on 2012-01-31**:
thanks Michikarg

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I can assume you're using the move_base node from the navigation stack, the local planner is configured out of the box to use dynamic window, but also supports trajectory rollout (http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner) The global planner uses Dijkstra's algorithm. (http://www.ros.org/wiki/navfn). HTH!

---

Originally posted by [jdt141](https://answers.ros.org/users/247/jdt141/) with karma: 118 on 2012-01-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdt141](https://answers.ros.org/users/247/jdt141/) on 2012-01-31**:
np. can you upvote or accept if helpful?

**Comment by [letmoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1610/letmoon/) on 2012-01-31**:
thanks jdt141